# How to create Radial flower effect like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, effects, blur

[image]

It is also seen that the flowers leave a nice trail.
Is there any tutorial to do this or similar?

I took this image [Radial streaks](http://s884.photobucket.com/user/TrojanMonkey/media/Action7.png.html) and added as a layer on top of my image with add blend mode and masked out the subject.. It doesn't look anyware close to the streaks in this image. Also i don't know how to add flowers randomly assuming I have a flower to add.

Comment: I guess the flowers were part of the picture as it was taken. This looks rather simple, but I haven't been able to reproduce the effect with either blurring or using displacement maps :/

Comment: No the flowers are not part of the picture, I think. The flowers are repeating. Look at the pattern I have marked now. Atleast some flowers are not

Comment: Good catch, you're right!

Comment: Even if they are repeating, that doesn't mean they were not stamped over the real flowers. I also think the original pictures had a nice setting and lot of flowers. And by the way, if you said there was a pattern then you already have half your solution....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to work with the Clone Stamp to build up the flowers. Have them on their own layer using Clone Stamp All Layers. Then duplicate it, blur it, mask parts to remove the blur. Duplicate again, mask other parts... repeat. In this case they probably also did some blurring of a grey, yellow, and brown overlay (colors chosen to match the outfits).

Using this starter image: https://unsplash.com/photos/mqtn_g1ogIY

Quickly masked out the people. But would be much better if you had an overhead photo of people in a field with some flowers.

[image]

Added some more flowers using Clone Stamp

[image]

Copied them around, very very poorly. Sorry, not my project. You can take your time and do this well though :)

[image]

Duplicated it (actually had already duplicated it above) so we can start to blur and mask and blur and mask and blur and mask and you get the idea. Blur different strengths of Radial Blur Zoom by using Smart Object.

[image]

Now, I renamed the non-blurred Flowers which rests on top to "Entirely Blurred" and using the mask can remove some of the flowers leaving only the streaks:

[image]

Figured now is a good time to put in new grass, mostly because I'm doing this quickly and haphazardly. Ideally, you'll use a photo that doesn't involve needing all new grass.

[image]

Blur the field and mask the focal

[image]

For composition the Radial Blur is going to work from the center. The people are off-center. Easy enough... group and move the flowers + blurs:

[image]

Then just keep adding more flowers and more blurs, here's a few more on the right side.

[image]

I'm only using White Flowers but you could bring in more color using different colored flowers and hue adjustments maybe with some Outer Glow as well

Comment: What kind of blur would you use to get the 'starburst' effect? I tried multiple, but couldn't find a satisfying one.

Comment: @Vincent I always do these by using a stock image with the blur and by modifying it with different transparency, layer masks and blending modes. Works 100% fine!

Comment: @go-meek What kind of blur? :)

Comment: @Vincent I have no name for this but I'd use a "burst of light" like this http://www.99centdrumkits.com/free-nook-wallpapers/images/orange-light-burst-nook-wallpaper.jpg. Then add an irregular circular gradient on a layer layer mask, poke a hole in the middle, duplicate + rotate + use a different blending mode on that "burst", and do some magic here and there, all this on a flowery field background, et voilà! Oh, and I could add a few more flowers or even puppies, whatever you want! (Very similar to what Ryan explained!)

Comment: You can probably create that burst by doing a star with lot of points in Illustrator, adding some blur on them in Photoshop and duplicating+rotating  it, at smaller size. That is, if I want to re-invent the wheel. I guess I'd get close to that burst effect.

Answer (score 1):

There's certainly a few steps missing in your process. Doing this from scratch requires some skills and there's probably 100 ways to get to that result.

Photographers use all sort of basic filters (or whatever they call it) that are not so special. It helps when the photo already has some effect from the start and good subjects too. A photographer could probably expand on this as I'm a total beginner in photography.

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/14462-REG/Cokin_CP185_P185_Radial_Zoom_Resin.html

[image: radial zoom lense]

Additionally to my comments about using burst and stamping flowers all over the place, you can explore the different blurs in Photoshop such as the radial blur filter. There's also the smudge tool that can help.

http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/action-zoom/

[image: radial blur Photoshop]

To add flowers randomly, you do as Ryan suggested and you get to work. I'm quite sure the original picture had a field of flowers already but if yours don't have any, find one that has a good angle for this. You can also isolate a few flowers with a layer mask and duplicate these layers to make your montage, as you would for any montage. That will in fact give you better results if you need to create a big format.

[image]

__

Obviously the results will depend on your skills, and how much time you spend on this.  A combo of all the suggestions you got so far will certainly get you closer to that effect in the picture. I don't think you should limit yourself to using 3 layers... you'll probably need a few more than that!